# LuckyBackup superuser scheduled backups do not run

Tags: cron, ubuntu-studio, schedule

I am currently running Ubuntu Studio 20.10 on a Dell desktop PC.  I have two different accounts, and would like to use LuckyBackup in superuser mode to run the backups and retain permissions.  The backups work fine manually; however, backups scheduled through the gui do not run.  I've tried several things, including running the scheduled backup in console mode to avoid X-server issues.  I've searched the internet, but have not found a solution.  I did look at the crontab; it showed that the run was stored in /usr/bin/luckybackup.  Any ideas as to how I can get the backup to run automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting you have missed:

Go to:

```
Profile > Schedule > Add (or modify) and set Console Mode
```

[image]

[reference](https://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=12709.0)

Comment: I actually tried that (as a quick test); however, it did not work.  That's why I asked here.

Comment: This worked for me on openSUSE 15.4

Answer (score 0):

I found that the backup worked okay as a normal user, and will not use the superuser and scheduling.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Kubuntu 20.04, and I found that luckybackup in super user mode does not run; actually it starts and quits immediately.
I found that it can run in super usee mode with the GUI by running it from a terminal using the command:
/usr/bin/sudo luckybackup

I assume that if crontab can issue that command it is possible that your scheduled backups will run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll look into how to do this.  For now, I'm running LuckyBackup scheduling in normal user mode.